# Flexbox horizontal scrolling issue in Chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, flexbox, scrollbar

I have a scenario with **flex** wrapper that contains header and content wrapper with overflow:auto. If the content wrapper has vertical scrolling, there is the following issue (in Chrome only):

The content can ends behind the vertical scrollbar without displaying horizontal scrollbar. The horizontal scrollbar appears only if the content overflows the border of the content wrapper.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpb6v31e/) sample where last letters of the first `<li>` are not visible. Even though there is not horizontal scrollbar. It appears after you add more letters.

Could you advice me for some workaround?